# How to solve $U_{xy} + U_x + x + y = 1$ in a simple way?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, substitution

I have to solve the following PDE:

$$U_{xy} + U_x + x + y = 1$$

Additionally, I have the initial conditions $u(0,y) = 0$ and $u(x, 0) = 0$.

The reason why I am struggling with this in particular is, because it seems that there is a way to solve this without using the advanced procedures that are usually necessary to solve 2nd order PDEs. I tried to substitute with $v = u_x$ but it did not really get me to the solution (I have the result in Maple to check).

Any ideas?

Comment: Assume that $v=u_x+x+y-1$, then $v_y=u_{xy}+1$, so the given equation will be $$v_y+v=1.$$Hope this helps.

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you very much. This substitution lead me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If we can find a particular solution $U^*(x, y)$, then writing the original p.d.e. in terms of $V = U - U^*$ yields the easier homogeneous p.d.e.
$$V_{xy} + V_x = 0 .$$

Substituting a general quadratic ansatz,
$$U^*(x, y) = A x^2 + B x y + C y^2 + D x + E y + F$$
gives $A = -\frac12, B = -1, D = 2,$ so taking $C = E = F = 0$ gives the particular solution $$U^*(x, y) = -\frac12 x^2 - x y + 2 x .$$

> **Additional Hint** Writing the homogeneous p.d.e. in $W = V_x$ gives the o.d.e. $$W_y + W = 0,$$ so $$W = e^{-y} G(x)$$ for some function $G(x)$, hence the general solution to the homogeneous p.d.e. is $$V = e^{-y} G(x) + H(y).$$ Now it remains just to impose the boundary conditions on $$U = V + U^* = e^{-y} G(x) + H(y) -\frac12 x^2 - x y + 2 x .$$

Comment: Thank you for your response, I took a different route and ended up with $u(x,y)=x*(\frac{4-x-2y}{2})-e^{-y}*C_1(x)+C_2(y)$. But how do I now use the initial conditions? When I just plug them in I get:

$0 = e^{-y}*C_1(0)+C_2(y)$
and
$0 = 2x-\frac{x^2}{2}-C_1(x)+C_2(0)$

How would I get a concrete result without C_1 and C_2?

Comment: Solving the $2$ equations you derived from the initial condition give $C_2(y) = -C_1(0) e^{-y}$ and $C_1(x) = \frac12 x^2 - 2 x + C_2(0)$, and evaluating at $y = 0, x = 0$, resp., gives $C_2(0) = -C_1(0)$. So, set $A := -C_1(0) = C_2(0)$ and substitute in our expressions for $C_1(x), C_2(y)$. The final result $U(x, y)$ shouldn't depend on $A$.